# Iterating over characters in a string in POSIX sh

Tags: shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Enter sequence:  " seq

for char in $seq; do
    echo "$char"
done
```

I read sequence of "characters" from standard input. For example let it be `1234(),`

I want to change it to be like this:

```
'1' '2' '3' '4' '(' ')' ','
```

I don't want to echo this sequence. I need it to has this new value.

Is it possible in standard sh script ?

Comment: Hmm. There's a very nice answer in bash or ksh that doesn't involve the overhead of external tools, but the POSIX sh requirement makes that harder.

Comment: What should happen if the user types a space? What if `seq="hello world"`?

Comment: BTW, in most cases, wrapping in single quotes isn't likely to be a useful behavior. When read from a command substitution, those quotes are literal, not syntactic, so they don't prevent evaluation in any way.

Comment: So this is why for seq= '1' '+' '1',  `expr $seq` does not work?

Comment: Right, if `seq=" '1' '+' '1' "`, then `expr $seq` runs `seq \'1\' \'+\' \'1\'` -- the extra backslashes are just showing the difference between _syntactical_ quotes (which are the time that `expr '1' '+' '1'` has) and _literal_ quotes (which are the kind you get from that expansion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string with `sed`(1):

```
seq=`printf "%s\n" "$seq" | sed 's/./ &/g'`
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "$seq"` is going to be less side-effecting than `echo $seq`. Search for "implementation-defined" in [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) if you want to be horrified -- and note the advice in the APPLICATION USAGE section. Also, the lack of quotes on `echo $seq` means you're replacing `*` with a list of files in the current directory, tabs with spaces (assuming a default IFS), etc.

Comment: Since command substitutions implicitly delete trailing newlines, I'm not so sure that there really is any advantage there.

Comment: It's ok, but i want to wrap each character of string with single quote. You code give me 1 2 3 (from 123) instead of '1' '2' '3'

Comment: You can modify the replacement string in the sed command: `sed "s/./ '&'/g"`

Comment: How can I delete leading space from this string ?

Comment: `seq="$(expr substr "$(printf "%s\n" "$seq" | sed 's/./ &/g')" 2 200)"` - not pretty, but works. Choose 2nd number (e.g. `200`) large enough to ensure it is longer than string.

Answer (score 1):

This works with all printable ASCII characters (and probably with anything that's not the NUL byte), without the help of external programs (`printf` is usually built-in):

```bash
string="$(printf "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!\"#\$%%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~ \t\n\r")"
while [ -n "${string}" ]; do
    character="$(printf '%c.' "${string}")"
    character="${character%.}"
    echo "Character: '${character}'"
    string="${string#?}"
done
```

Notice the extra non-whitespace character in the format string. We need it so the command substitution doesn't strip away a possible `LF`.

```
Character: '0'
Character: '1'
Character: '2'
Character: '3'
Character: '4'
Character: '5'
Character: '6'
Character: '7'
Character: '8'
Character: '9'
Character: 'a'
Character: 'b'
Character: 'c'
Character: 'd'
Character: 'e'
Character: 'f'
Character: 'g'
Character: 'h'
Character: 'i'
Character: 'j'
Character: 'k'
Character: 'l'
Character: 'm'
Character: 'n'
Character: 'o'
Character: 'p'
Character: 'q'
Character: 'r'
Character: 's'
Character: 't'
Character: 'u'
Character: 'v'
Character: 'w'
Character: 'x'
Character: 'y'
Character: 'z'
Character: 'A'
Character: 'B'
Character: 'C'
Character: 'D'
Character: 'E'
Character: 'F'
Character: 'G'
Character: 'H'
Character: 'I'
Character: 'J'
Character: 'K'
Character: 'L'
Character: 'M'
Character: 'N'
Character: 'O'
Character: 'P'
Character: 'Q'
Character: 'R'
Character: 'S'
Character: 'T'
Character: 'U'
Character: 'V'
Character: 'W'
Character: 'X'
Character: 'Y'
Character: 'Z'
Character: '!'
Character: '"'
Character: '#'
Character: '$'
Character: '%'
Character: '&'
Character: '''
Character: '('
Character: ')'
Character: '*'
Character: '+'
Character: ','
Character: '-'
Character: '.'
Character: '/'
Character: ':'
Character: ';'
Character: '<'
Character: '='
Character: '>'
Character: '?'
Character: '@'
Character: '['
Character: '\'
Character: ']'
Character: '^'
Character: '_'
Character: '`'
Character: '{'
Character: '|'
Character: '}'
Character: '~'
Character: ' '
Character: '    '
Character: '
'
'haracter: '
```

For long strings, `sed` will probably be faster.

Comment: I'm surprised you're going this route rather than the offset/length parameter expansion, which I'd think would involve less memory reallocation. And if you know you're stripping exactly one character, why not use `?` unconditionally rather than substituting that one character into the expression?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The question is about POSIX sh, so substring expansion (which would normally be the obvious solution) is not supported. You're right about your second point, though. Updated.